# Prepared statement in R - dbSendQuery does not work with dates

Tags: r, prepared-statement, rpostgresql, r-dbi

I am trying to write a prepared statement with dbSendQuery. My issue is that the data frame of inputs are converted to numeric values, but two of the three inputs are dates. This results in the following error message:

**Warning: Error in postgresqlExecStatement: RS-DBI driver: (could not Retrieve the result : ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "17624"
)**

My code is as follows:

```
query = dbSendQuery(con,"
                            SELECT

                            ***AL LOT OF TABLE AND JOINS***

                            WHERE

                            users_terminals.user_user_id = $1 and
                            planning_stops.planned_arrival >= $2 and
                            planning_stops.planned_arrival <= $3"
                            ,
                            data.frame(user$users_users_id,
                                          datefrom, 
                                          dateto))

        tmp = dbFetch(query)
        dbClearResult(query)
```

The numeric value of datefrom is 17624, so this make me think that $2 is replaced by as.numeric(datefrom) when I run the command. Also, user$users_users_id is a numeric value and I do not get an error for that one. Probably the whole data frame is converted to numeric.

I have created a workaround, but it is not an optimal situation and I would like to understand what happens here. The workaround I created is:

```
query = dbSendQuery(con,"
                            SELECT

                            ***AL LOT OF TABLE AND JOINS***

                            WHERE

                            users_terminals.user_user_id = $1 and
                            EXTRACT(day from planning_stops.planned_arrival - '1970-01-01') >= $2 and
                            EXTRACT(day from planning_stops.planned_arrival - '1970-01-01') <= $3"
                            ,
                            data.frame(user$users_users_id,
                                          datefrom, 
                                          dateto))

        tmp = dbFetch(query)
        dbClearResult(query)
```

Could anyone help me out here? The workaround works for now, but it does not seem to be optimal.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

I have read something about sqlInterpolate, so I thought let's give it a try. However, I still receive an error message:

**Error in postgresqlExecStatement(conn, statement, ...) : 
  RS-DBI driver: (could not Retrieve the result : ERROR:  operator does not exist: timestamp without time zone >= integer
LINE 57: ...                   planning_stops.planned_arrival >= 2018-04...
                                                              ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
)**

My code is now:

```
 query = sqlInterpolate(con,"
                                SELECT

                                ***AL LOT OF TABLE AND JOINS***

                                WHERE

                                users_terminals.user_user_id = ?id1 and
                                planning_stops.planned_arrival >= ?date1 and
                                planning_stops.planned_arrival <= ?date2"
                                ,
                                id1 = user$users_users_id,
                                date1 = datefrom, 
                                date2 = dateto)

            tmp = dbGetQuery(con, 
                     query)
```

Still not working though.. It seems sqlInterpolate converts the inputs to integer.

Comment: Are you using *RPostgeSQL* or *RPostges*?

Comment: I am using _RPostgeSQL_

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the dates as strings and convert them to `DATE` in the query:

```r
query = sqlInterpolate(con,"SELECT ... WHERE
                                users_terminals.user_user_id = ?id1 AND
                                planning_stops.planned_arrival >= ?date1::DATE AND
                                planning_stops.planned_arrival <= ?date2::DATE"
                                ,
                                id1 = user$users_users_id,
                                date1 = strftime(datefrom, "%Y-%m-%d"),
                                date2 = strftime(dateto, "%Y-%m-%d"))
tmp = dbGetQuery(con,  query)
```

If you would like to pass a timestamp instead, just use the appropriate format in strftime() and convert to `timestamp` in the query.